# Who was in the Security Council?

Tags: star-wars

Inspired by [Why didn't the Jedi enact Order 65?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51291/why-didnt-the-jedi-enact-order-65).

Order 65 (copied from linked question):

> Order 65 was one of the 150 contingency orders that the clone troopers of the Grand Army of the Republic were trained to carry out in the event of different emergency scenarios during the Clone Wars. Order 65 stated that if a majority of the Senate or the Security Council declared that the Supreme Chancellor—at that time Palpatine—was unfit for duty, the Chancellor was to be captured or, if necessary, killed.

Is there any canon on what parties make up the Security Council? Is it a mix of senators and Jedi? Is security council = Jedi council?

Comment: I'm aware the question linked provides a Wiki link that loosely defines the council. Just wondering if that's the best definition out there.

Comment: Interestingly there is also the Security and Intelligence Council, composed of Palpatine's inner circle.  Hard to tell if they are the same thing.  It seems unlikely as they don't seem associated with the Senate and act more like a war cabinet.  If they were, it would also provide an answer to the linked question because it would have been pointless to ask them to help overthrow him.

Comment: @FGreg - unless Wiki has citations, it's not canon in any way. So it's a perfectly valid and even great question

Comment: Who wrote these orders? Isn't 66 the one to wipe out the Jedi, including babies?? If Palp wrote that one, why include 65? Or did everyone have his own set of orders and no editing was done??

Answer (score 1):

There's a more detailed version of Order 65 in "[Republic Commando - True Colors](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Republic_Commando:_True_Colors)"

> Order 65: In the event of either (i) a majority in the Senate
>   declaring the Supreme Commander (Chancellor) to be unfit to issue
>   orders, **or (ii) the Security Council declaring him to be unfit to
>   issue orders,** and an authenticated order being received by the GAR,
>   commanders shall be authorized to detain the Supreme Commander, with
>   lethal force if necessary, and command of the GAR shall fall to the
>   acting Chancellor until a successor is appointed or alternative
>   authority identified as outlined in Section 6 (iv).

There's also a further mention of the Council in "[Star Wars : Clone Wars : Gambit - Siege](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zptEji73U-sC&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230&dq=%22security%20council%22%20and%20%22star%20wars%22&source=bl&ots=4A7Jf5yq7C&sig=mSIhtWKhzX1f5IWMz89Fli8SfzE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TIhmVJmdMsvkasvagMAL&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22security%20council%22&f=false)" where they explictly refer to it as the ***Senate*** Security Council.

---

There's no specific indication of *who* comprises the Security Council but it seems clear that this is a grouping within the Senate, presumably comprising those Senators who are providing the bulk of the military assistance and ships to the Grand Army of the Republic.