# Why didn't all the Jedi across the galaxy sense the clones before their deaths?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, clones

In Revenge of the Sith, Palpatine told all the Clone Commanders across the galaxy, to execute Order 66.

While the Jedi were on missions, the clones were given an order and not one Jedi sensed anything.

If they did sense it, could they have escaped? Or did the Dark Side hide the clones?

Comment: [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/131075/31936) to one of your earlier question seems to answer this one, too: "War itself pours darkness into the Force, deepening the cloud that limits Jedi perception. And the clones have no malice, no hatred, not the slightest ill intent that might give warning. They are only following orders." How is this question different?

Comment: Also, Order 66 was executed *nearly simultaneously* across the galaxy. There was no time for them to sense anything other than that something was terribly, terribly wrong, which then impeded their ability to use the Force.

Comment: see also [Why didn't the Jedi (besides Yoda) sense the coming of Order 66?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/74069/5184) and the possible dupe [Why did the Jedi fail to get information about Order 66?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10874/5184). dvk's answer there touches on this.

Comment: @Null - I agree. My answer to the dupe deals with all of the points raised above; Why the malice of the clones wasn't detected, the shroud of the dark side, the timescales involved, the impact of the change in orientation of the Force.