# If the Jedi are so attuned to other life forms, why aren't they overwhelmed by the suffering in the Galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

It takes sudden and massive losses of life to shake them but most of the Empire-controlled planets led miserable lives, how come, say, little baby twi'lek's death by famine in Ryloth didn't shake Ben or Yoda? We can presume that stuff like that happens every minute in an Empire-controlled Galaxy.

EDIT: I don't believe this question has anything to do with being able to read the intentions of Anakin and his legion during Order 66, this question is about why don't the Jedi feel all the suffering in the Galaxy, I think they might feel it to a degree but they train to lessen those effects, IIRC, that theme was touched lightly in the Shatterpoint novel and was part of what turned Depa, but I don't really know any other answer other than them suppressing their own senses a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why didn't all the Jedi at the Jedi Temple sense Anakin and his legion of Clones’ thoughts?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131073/why-didnt-all-the-jedi-at-the-jedi-temple-sense-anakin-and-his-legion-of-clones)

Comment: Probably for the same reason none of us hear the suffering on our planet - there's too much of it and it's too homogeneous, so it becomes background noise that one can get used to.

Comment: But we aren't so attuned to as to be physically affected by any of that suffering as the Jedi have shown to be.

Comment: Shown to be *where*? Yoda sensed Alderaan because he was close at the moment. Leia sensed Luke and Han because they shared affection.

Comment: The one who we see react to it was Ben, and yeah, maybe proximity is a factor but then again, Yoda was in Kashyyyk when Order 66 happened and he was shaken by all the deaths, far and close.

Comment: Nice catch with Yoda. I could counter that with Yoda being an exceptionally talented and experienced Force user - it is very unlikely that all Jedi were on par with him. Interesting how the answer you accepted tell basically the same thing.

Comment: @Neo It is also worth noting there that Yoda felt _Order 66_; that is, he felt the demise of thousands of highly trained Force users. From a sensing-a-change-in-the-Force perspective, the death of a Jedi, someone who is closely connected to and able to influence and channel the Force directly, is quite likely to leave a much greater imprint on the sensible Force than the death of people whose connection to the Force is peripheral to nonexistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's somewhat along the lines of...

If you've ever been bitten by a mosquito, kinda annoying but tolerable.

Imagine getting bitten by a million more.  It's going to stagger you...

It's called [inurement](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inurement)...

Aside from that, I don't believe they were all that sensitive to the Force anyway.  Until they learned to use [Force Sense](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_sense) which ***is*** a power..

> Force sense was among the most basic of Force abilities. It could be used to feel another being's feelings, the future, ripples in the Force caused by momentous or traumatic events, impending danger and the presence of the dark side.

Comment: This is probably the reason, I think it's an important aspect of Force Sense because it can go as far as to overwhelm and turn the best of the best, like it happened to Depa Billaba.

It's just that I suppossed that if that was the case, Jedi would have special teachings to suppress that negative input in particular, and I haven't been able to find any mention of it yet.

Comment: Why would you roll back to this ghastly revision of yours?! I did my best to respect your style when editing, but some grammar and spelling mistakes just aren't forgivable. Plus, your use of full stops is completely out of line!

Comment: It seems that adding the Edit section rolled it back, sorry..

Comment: he was talking to me actually..

Comment: @UmßraDivisio  -  for the sake of future edits, what exactly did you not like in my revision, given your own edits resemble mine more and more now?

Comment: @Gallifreian Mostly it was the reformatting in a sense of removing my purposeful full stops.  Aside from also removing the fact I was stating an opinion, you rewrote it to  "This is called inurement" which I didn't feet was an improvement.  So I rolled back and edited to make sure the corrections in spelling and grammar were still corrected while leaving my preferred format.  Mainly because it was easier to me than to go back and correct your edit back to the way I wanted it.

Comment: Those full stops are called [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis), and you're [using them wrong](http://writing-skills.com/five-annoying-ways-use-ellipsis), so they're not grammatically correct, let alone *purposeful*. If you wish to retain this revision, are least change the `inurement` link to lead to a dictionary, not a Google search.

Comment: obviously you [must be doing it wrong][1] because there is ample indications of how the ellipsis is also an acceptable grammar notation for a pause..  [1]: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50559/using-ellipsis-to-indicate-a-pause-in-conversation

Comment: The answer you linked quotes the *Chicago Style Manual*, which is not an authoritative source for *English grammar and punctuation*. Besides, I'm fairly confident that the Chicago manual refers to **reported speech**, when the person speaking is clearly having problem maintaining a discernible voice. In any case, ellipses don't look good in written text (unless used in quotations), especially in informative text, which we're supposed to produce on this website. Still, your answer - your rules.

Comment: @zabeus  -  why not just edit?

Comment: @zabeus  -  you certainly won't come to any harm, especially given that your edit will be first reviewed by the author of the post.

Comment: Since it seems you can't edit comments after 5 minutes here is another source for the ellipsis clarification. http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/ellipsis.htm

Comment: This link says the same thing as the precious one. You can use ellipses for omissions in quotations, or to report fluttering speech. Nowhere else - if you're using formal language.