# Why did Rex want to kill Ahsoka after receiving Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, ahsoka-tano

Order 66 was clear: Execute Jedi for their treason against the Republic. This is what clones were programmed to do, but when Rex received Order 66, Ahsoka was no longer a Jedi. So, why couldn't Rex resist the temptation to kill her?

From tactical point of view, Ahsoka could be threat to the Republic because she was an ally of the Jedi, but Order 66 doesn't say anything about terminating the allies of the Jedi.

Talking about following any orders of Darth Sidious, Darth Sidious didn't say anything about executing Ahsoka.

Comment: She's still pretty Jedi-like.

Comment: The clones aren't droids, they don't have a database of current jedi personnel in their heads. Maybe they *judge* who is a jedi, and this ironically made this the worst ship Ahsoka could have been on, because all of these clones had fought with her and saw her as a jedi, despite her "official" status.

Comment: @Harabeck All clones knew her official status. They had earlier even paid respect to her arrival by painting their armor with her skin color. At the very least, Rex knew.

Comment: @HarleyQuinn Correct, yes. This supports my earlier comment.

Answer (score 4):

Rex himself [gives the reason](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Order_66)

> Under this directive, any and all Jedi leadership must be executed for treason against the Republic. Any soldier that does not comply with the order will also be executed for treason.

Ahsoka wasn't a Jedi anymore, but she had been aiding the Jedi in the Clone Wars (before and after leaving the Order). More importantly *she had just been talking with the Jedi Council*. Yoda also contacts her and she implies she might be willing to rejoin the Jedi (but not yet). So if they are all now regarded as traitors, that makes Ahsoka complicit in their treachery.

Comment: Only brain chip and programming matter. Allies of the Jedi weren't targetted.

Answer (score 1):

## A Sith Deals In Absolutes

Order 66 was created by Darth Sidious, who is, notably, a Sith, so when we try to understand what *form* it took, it helps to look at how Sith think.

Darth Vader summarizes it best:

> If you're not with me, then you're my enemy.

Sidious is not interested in the subtleties of Temple politics. He is not interested in their sects, their offshoots. He doesn't care if you're an infant in the creches of the Temple or so old that you totter around the Archives. If you are a Force Sensitive that has *ever* been associated with the Temple, you *are* a Jedi, and you *are* a target.

The only way to *not* be a target is to actively align yourself with the Empire and the Sith. Neutrality is not acceptable. By a Sith definition, Ahsoka *was* a Jedi. Having a tiff with the Council and leaving the Temple didn't change that.

Comment: `By a Sith definition, Ahsoka was a Jedi.` ~> That's irrelevant unless you have a citation saying clones were fed a different definition of Order 66 than the one passed by Senate.

Comment: @HarleyQuinn Do you have the text of that order? I can't find a canon source for that. Either way, when we're talking a *programmed response* in a biochip. That definition is *very* relevant, because it determines exactly how that order was programmed. Programming does not work by just running `killAllJedi()`. You have to have a heuristic definition. Evidently, the heuristic definition included toddlers and Ahsoka, and my answer explains why.

Comment: If shooting infants in their cribs falls under the purview of Order 66, then it's clearly not required to demonstrate ideological adherence to the Jedi ways.

Comment: Order 66 is well defined in the canon. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10874/931

Comment: @HarleyQuinn Republic Commando isn’t canon — and even if it was,  I specified ‘infants in their cribs’, who certainly don’t meet the definition of officers, but were summarily murdered.

Comment: Younglings weren't murdered on Order 66 directive. Only clones could act on Order 66. That mission was led by Vader.

Comment: Do you think Vader went through the whole creche, lightsabering babies one by one? Come on. The clones did their part.

Comment: For that part, clones didn't need brain chip.

Answer (score 0):

> Why did Rex want to kill Ahsoka after receiving Order 66?

Order 66 was to kill the Jedi.

Ahsoka was still a Jedi.  She may have no longer been a member of the Jedi temple/order, but she still had all the same abilities as a Jedi.

It is no different than calling Luke Skywalker a Jedi.  He was a Jedi even though in his time the Jedi/temple order were long gone.

Comment: There's a difference between Jedi and force-sensitive. Force-sensitive is superset of Jedi, Sith, other force organizations and unaffiliated ones.