# Why did Rex order his troops to kill Maul after receiving Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, darth-maul, order-66

Order 66 was clear: Execute *Jedi* for their treason against the Republic.

But, after receiving Order 66, Rex also ordered his troops to kill Maul. Why? Maul wasn't a Jedi in any way.

I had asked a similar question for Ahsoka: [Why did Rex want to kill Ahsoka after receiving Order 66?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/243931/931)

In the case of Ahsoka, there's a grey area, but Maul was never a Jedi or an ally of the Jedi Order.

Why did Rex order his troops to kill Maul?

Comment: Could it have been an intentional "misinterpretation" of the order to do something he felt should be done?

Answer (score 3):

It could be due to Maul and Ahsoka connection to the force.

Please see also this video, there could be some insights concerning Ahsoka in particular:

Also from the video above:
In the 2018 Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith Comics, two inquisitors were killed by Purge Troopers, when they used the force to activate Order 66 in Purge Troopers chip. **So Troopers were just killing all who were able to use the Force.**

[image]

Comment: If you're relying on the video for evidence you really should [edit] the relevant parts into the answer in case the video goes down.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot video just states the same. Still TS could find some insights for himself.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi, the Purge Troopers killed the inquisitors because the Jedi they were hunting knew the inquisitors and demanded they kill the ‘Jedi’